# Color elements black and white with JS

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I saw this page and I really like the lightbox effect, wehen you klick on the image, the lightbox opens and all the other elements in the background become black and white.

Example:
https://soundcloud.com/pepski-sound/pepskii-knowledge-the-cat-1

How can I do that with jQuery and colorbox?

Comment: It's a layer with some opacity. Try something by yourself and ask us only specific problems

Comment: Ok, whats the layer called, because I haven't found anything.